# How to provide public access to web api?

Tags: iis

I deployed the code in iis (under default web site), what i need to do to access this api from an external consumer (provide public access).

Can anybody explain how the following works, and what is the username and password here(which username and password)?

```
*****IIS listens on all the specified ports for requests employing a URL of the general format:
protocol://[username:password@]domain[:port]/path/file[?parameters]*****
```

Comment: I believe that we will need a lot more information to answer this question, what is the code you are talking about? how we will guess username and password of yours? and what have you tried so far? ... or may be I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Some clients provide support for providing the username and password for `basic authentication` as part of the URL. You can refer to [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) for more information.

**From Section 3.1**

> While the syntax for the rest of the URL may vary depending on the
>   particular scheme selected, URL schemes that involve the direct use
>   of an IP-based protocol to a specified host on the Internet use a
>   common syntax for the scheme-specific data:
>
> ```
>     //<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>
> ```
>
> Some or all of the parts ":@", ":",
>   ":", and "/" may be excluded.  The scheme specific
>   data start with a double slash "//" to indicate that it complies with 
>   the common Internet scheme syntax. The different components obey the
>   following rules:
>
> ```
> user
>     An optional user name. Some schemes (e.g., ftp) allow the
>     specification of a user name.
>
> password
>     An optional password. If present, it follows the user
>     name separated from it by a colon.
> ```

`Postman Echo` has some public endpoints that you can use for testing different `auth` mechanisms. You can use their [Basic Auth endpoint](https://docs.postman-echo.com/#42c867ca-e72b-3307-169b-26a478b00641) to do some testing. Another way to use `Basic Auth` is to set the `Authorization` header with the credentials encoded as a Base64 string; if the server can decode the string and validate the credentials, it'll authenticate you and allow the request.

An example of an `Authorization` header using `Basic Auth`:

> Authorization: Basic cG9zdG1hbjpwYXNzd29yZA==

You also want to ensure that your requests are being sent over `SSL`.

Hope this helps!